# Hide address bar google chrome mobile on scroll up

Tags: google-chrome, mobile

I was wondering if is there a way to hide the address bar (or don't show up) on google chrome when you scroll up to the content. In safari, it is automatic, the address bar shows only on the top of the page but not in google chrome.

Is there an issues about it ?

I tried with scrollTo(0,1); but works only one time and that's not the effect that I wanted.